# Mocking / stubbing non-virtual methods in .NET

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino-mocks, stub, moles

What .NET mocking or stubbing frameworks exist that can stub non-virtual (or even static) methods like Microsoft [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/)? It would be nice to have something like RhinoMocks `AssertWasCalled`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there is one more : [Justmock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)
I've tried those 3 frameworks and I chose **Moles**. It's true that it only stub things and it's your job to change them into mocks, but finally it's not too hard (even if I found that the tutorial was not enough clear).

There are already topics on what framework to choose, like [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx).

If you really want pre-programmed verifications on your calls, spend money for Justmock or Typemock (more expensive but still the leader).

Answer (score 3):

I know of two:

1. Moles
2. TypeMock